# Audio content analysis for online audiovisual data

Tags: audio, video-processing, multimedia

I want to work on a project where I have to segment and classify online audiovisual data based on its audio content, i.e. different parts of the audio visual data will be segmented and classified as silence, music, speech, speech+background music, etc based on their audio content.

I am aware that I have to obtain the audio part from the audiovisual data and extract features like zero crossing, spectral peaks, etc. and find out segment boundaries in order to segment audio data.

But I'm lost in the beginning itself.

I do not know how to start off with the project. The output of the software are segments of audiovisual data under different categories like silence, speech, music, etc.

It will be really helpful if someone lets me know

- Which programming language is convenient for this purpose?
- What steps should i follow in order to develop this software?

I have no background in digital signal processing. It'll be really helpful if I get some guidance

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look into a multimedia framework such as [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org). It is crossplatform, but the easiest to get started on Linux where it originates from. It already comes with all kind of plugins to receve, demux and decode audio and video. It also has a couple of analyzers (such as level and spectrum analyzers for audio as well as voice activity detection). Those could be a good starting point for your experiments. Gstreamer itself is written in C, but applications can use the language bindings to python, perl, c#, c++, java, ...